# To direct http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

We need to direct http to https. Below is our rewrite rule. URLs without www are redirecting to HTTPS. But the urls like http://www.xxxx.in/case-studies/ are not directing to https.

http://xxxx.in/case-studies/ - This is directing to https

http://www.xxxx.in/case-studies/ - This is not directing to https

Please help. Thanks.

```
.....
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
.....
```

Comment: Is this wordpress .htaccess? There is no rule shown here to redirect `http -> https`.

Comment: Yes. This is wordpress .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-htaccess/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

will work for all traffic, I just did a quick test on my server and it worked well, let me know if it doesn't for you. Note this will do all web traffic, if you wish to only do it for a certain domain, that example is included in the reference site, but this will work in general.

Comment: in what way did it? as in just refused to load, or did the webpage display a specific error

Comment: Hi, This is working. Thanks. May be cache issue. After refresh this is working.

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown attempts/samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs, also I have fixed your `"` quotes problem in your htaccess along with regex for query string matching here.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_SSL:_ssl]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} w3tc_preview [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_PREVIEW:_preview]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC} -f
    RewriteRule .* /wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:W3TC_SSL}%{ENV:W3TC_PREVIEW}.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Without www is directing to https

With www is not directing to https

Comment: @SODC, sorry but I can't see any difference between both sample links which you pinged here.

Comment: Actually I am not able to post the full url here. I have edited my initial post. Thanks

Comment: @SODC, ok so you mean www url is not redirecting?

Comment: Yes. That is Correct

Comment: @SODCmy rules should take care of both type of URLs actually, do you have any other Rules other than shown?

Comment: Yes. This is a WordPress website. Full file is here http://www.sierratec.com/downloads/ref-08062021.docx

Comment: @SODC, Sorry, not able to access this link, could you please do confirm if you have any other htaccess file present in your system apart from this one?

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236734/wordpress-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https-via-htaccess

```
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
```

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]